# Looking for the name of a 90's coin op game where you played a barbarian with an axe. Not Golden Axe

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for the name of a 90's coin op game. It was a platformer and you controlled a barbarian with an axe. Holding down the fire button made the axe power up for one powerful hit. There were enemies that curl into balls and bounced around. You also attacked larger enemies, possibly end of level bosses. I think the name of the game was a single word. It's not Rastan, Rygar or Golden Axe.

Comment: This is definitely a coin op — no chance of confusion there? Otherwise I'd suggest Legendary Axe, a home game for the PC Engine: https://youtu.be/9Ucw8ceyRYs?t=1286

Comment: Wow! So the arcade box contained a PC Engine inside? This was in South Africa btw. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Tommy you should provide that as an answer not as a comment and then it can be approved because apparently it's the right answer.

Comment: @RowanHawkins sure; I hadn’t quite figured out the arcade angle until today, but done.

Answer (score 6):

The game was [The Legendary Axe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legendary_Axe), in principle an exclusive to the PC Engine home console, but [it appears that](https://bootleggames.fandom.com/wiki/TourVision_PC_Engine) a company called TourVision created and distributed a bootleg version of the PC Engine for arcade use, allowing players to purchase time rather than the more conventional credits or continues.